# Jenkins can't find make.exe

Tags: jenkins, cygwin

I'm trying to install jenkins on windows and I have Cygwin.
I provided the bash.exe path to jenkins and add a job which executes a .sh file.
The output is like:

```
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Build_Release
[Build_Release] $ C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe -xe C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\jenkins8276366787192439492.sh
+ cd /cygdrive/d/01-Avelabs/001-Projects/001-VGTT/001-Repos/P2.4.0.5/host/AdasHost/Application/
+ ./BuildHost.sh
./BuildHost.sh: line 2: make: command not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Jenkins is not a cygwin program so it could not work at all as you are passing `C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\jenkins8276366787192439492.sh` and not a cywin path. In addition you are not running bash as login shell so the PATH could be improperly set to find make.

Answer (score 0):

To get you going (the problem is not obvious but it should be easy enough to debug): Add a "set" command at the top of the script to dump the environment variables, including the PATH.  You will very likely find that PATH is not in any of the folders listed in the value of the PATH env var.  (You could also put simply, "echo $PATH".)

Some possibilities:

When I start bash in Windows I typically inherit the Windows path, but not the Linux path:  /cygdrive/c/windows/system32 is included, but /bin is not.  So, even basic Linux commands like "ls" result in "command not found" errors.  I'll typically start a bash session with "export PATH=/bin:$PATH" to get around this.

Even if you initialize the path with a .bash_profile script, the user under which Jenkins is executing is probably not executing the same initialization script.

Finally - and not meaning to say "Is it plugged in? - but: I ran a clean Cygwin install and did not get make by default.  So be sure it is included in /your/ installation!

Comment: Thanks for your reply.make.exe and other tools are installed and I can use them through bash.exe --login